# Where is 64-bit Mac (AMD64) version now?

Tags: 64-bit, mac, downloads

Sometime ago on on download page (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) was an option for download "64-bit Mac (AMD64) version". Why it was deleted?

Answer (score 1):

It's not deleted, just moved: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/

Alternatively, you can click on the [Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) link, pick a mirror from the *Other Images* section.